# External devices crash - BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, kernel, adapter

Every time I wake/boot and login and start working, all of the usb devices connected to the hub stop working sometime within the first ~10 minutes of being logged in. The display continues to work normally and I can still use the built in keyboard and touchpad to use the laptop. Disconnecting/reconnecting the hub fixes it and I am then able to use the system as long as I like with no issues.

System info:

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a Dell XPS 13 9370 (2018) and I've been having this crash issue for years, all the way back to 18.04.

This laptop only has USB-C ports, specifically:

- Two Thunderbolt 3 (USB Type-C) ports with Power Delivery
- One USB 3.1 Gen 1 (USB Type-C) port with Power Delivery/DisplayPort

So I've always had to use some form of a USB-C -> display adapter or hub to connect a monitor and m/kb to it. I'm currently using a hub by gofranco that includes ports: 1 HDMI, DisplayPort, 2 USB-A, 1 SD, 1 USB-C, and 1 ethernet; but this has happened on whatever multiport adapter I've ever used.

I'm connecting my 3440x1440@49.99Hz monitor to the hub via HDMI along with my mouse and keyboard via USB-A, and plugging the hub into one of the two Thunderbolt ports on the laptop.

I captured some `dmesg -wH` output of the crash:

```c
[Jun26 17:16] usb 3-1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  +9.721054] usb 3-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.130583] usb 3-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2f96, idProduct=0200, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1.2: Product: Antlion USB Microphone
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Antlion Audio
[  +0.003489] hid-generic 0003:2F96:0200.0016: No inputs registered, leaving
[  +0.000052] hid-generic 0003:2F96:0200.0016: hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Device [Antlion Audio Antlion USB Microphone] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.1.2/input2
[  +0.034405] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  +0.220856] hid-generic 0005:1000:0006.0017: unknown main item tag 0x0
[  +0.000048] input: BLE_ATH-M50xBT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3/0005:1000:0006.0017/input/input57
[  +0.000082] hid-generic 0005:1000:0006.0017: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v10.01 Device [BLE_ATH-M50xBT] on 9c:b6:d0:8d:68:2a
[  +1.920870] input: BLE_ATH-M50xBT (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input58
[  +5.704056] retire_capture_urb: 287 callbacks suppressed
[  +0.691828] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  +0.000020] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  +0.000008] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000001] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +5.139475] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  +0.000019] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  +0.000007] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000003] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000001] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
```

It seems to have something to do with the `BAR 15: failed to assign [mem]` stuff, but I also see that happening after disconnect/reconnect the hub and the devices are coming back up and have no further crashes:

```c
[  +0.556537] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 4
[  +0.000007] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  +0.000002] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  +0.000002] usb 4-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  +0.001207] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[  +0.000008] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  +0.000014] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
[  +0.000005] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  +0.008656] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  +0.367879] usb 3-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  +0.497551] usb 3-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  +0.017162] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[  +0.000006] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[  +0.001386] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: dma_pool_destroy xHCI input/output contexts, 00000000b8684732 busy
[  +0.000010] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: dma_pool_destroy xHCI input/output contexts, 00000000b1a23e38 busy
[  +0.000061] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[  +0.028993] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  +0.000016] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  +0.000008] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.703247] pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15d4] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[  +0.000027] pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc3f00000-0xc3f0ffff]
[  +0.000079] pci 0000:39:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[  +0.000130] pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
[  +0.000002] pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[  +0.000099] pci 0000:39:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:04:02.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link)
[  +0.000226] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  +0.000019] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  +0.000009] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000003] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000004] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000305] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[  +0.000006] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[  +0.001132] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000200009810
[  +0.000291] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[  +0.000004] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[  +0.000004] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[  +0.000074] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.19
[  +0.000005] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000002] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  +0.000002] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
[  +0.000002] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
[  +0.000203] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000015] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[  +0.001023] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.19
[  +0.000004] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000004] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  +0.000002] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
[  +0.000002] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
[  +0.000173] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000012] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[  +0.251787] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.152065] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice= 3.a4
[  +0.000006] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[  +0.001363] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000287] hub 3-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[  +0.347460] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.721591] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 3.a4
[  +0.000006] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000002] usb 4-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[  +0.000002] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[  +0.002728] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000107] hub 4-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0.538648] usb 4-1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.022349] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0620, bcdDevice=93.03
[  +0.000005] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB3.1 Hub
[  +0.000001] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[  +0.062758] hub 4-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000855] hub 4-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0.065677] usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.150447] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610, bcdDevice=93.03
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[  +0.001092] hub 3-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0.000256] hub 3-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0.136146] usb 3-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.152566] usb 3-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c539, bcdDevice=39.04
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.2: Product: USB Receiver
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  +0.011113] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C539.0018: hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.2/input0
[  +0.059404] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C539.0019: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.2/input1
[  +0.028951] usb 3-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.030470] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C539.001A: hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.2/input2
[  +0.059487] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C539.001A: device of type eQUAD Lightspeed 1 (0x0c) connected on slot 1
[  +0.004945] input: Logitech G Pro  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.001A/0003:046D:4079.001B/input/input59
[  +0.000293] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4079.001B: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech G Pro ] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.2/input2:1
[  +0.035904] usb 3-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2f96, idProduct=0200, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.1.2: Product: Antlion USB Microphone
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Antlion Audio
[  +0.011584] hid-generic 0003:2F96:0200.001C: No inputs registered, leaving
[  +0.000034] hid-generic 0003:2F96:0200.001C: hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Antlion Audio Antlion USB Microphone] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.1.2/input2
[  +0.113275] usb 3-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.149405] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=0296, bcdDevice=11.01
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.3: Product: USB-HID Keyboard
[  +0.012260] input: USB-HID Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/0003:04D9:0296.001D/input/input61
[  +0.058434] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0296.001D: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB-HID Keyboard] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.3/input0
[  +0.001041] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0296.001E: hiddev2,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [USB-HID Keyboard] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.3/input1
[  +0.001388] input: USB-HID Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0296.001F/input/input62
[  +0.057630] input: USB-HID Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0296.001F/input/input63
[  +0.000057] input: USB-HID Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0296.001F/input/input64
[  +0.000089] input: USB-HID Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0296.001F/input/input65
[  +0.000063] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0296.001F: input,hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB-HID Keyboard] on usb-0000:39:00.0-1.3/input2
[  +0.079693] usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.102321] usb 3-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8888, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  +0.000005] usb 3-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.5: Product: USB Billboard Device
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1.5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[  +0.812808] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  +0.000019] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  +0.000007] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000002] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000003] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.000001] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  +0.115533] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4079.001B: HID++ 4.2 device connected.
```